# Использование функции VBA в вычисляемое поле сводной таблицы

Tags: excel, vba, макрос

При использовании пользовательской функции, написанной в VBA, в вычисляемом поле сводной таблицы excel выдает ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Код простенькой функции:

```
Function testfunc(keks)
   testfunc = keks * 2
End Function
```

На рабочем листе функция *testfunc()* прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cводные таблицы не умеют работать с пользовательскими формулами, только со штатными.

Comment: Совсем-совсем? Печальная новость. А Вы не в курсе, Power-pivot умеет это делать?

Comment: Совсем. Однако, ничего не мешает задействовать новую колонку в исходных данный, в которой будут значения, получаемые пользовательской формулой. Единственное неудобство - увеличение исходных данных. Про Power Pivot ничего сказать не могу, не приходилось использовать.